# Issues using certificates in terraform

Tags: ssl, terraform, csr

I'm facing some issues while dealing with certificates in terraform.
Before writing the code below, i've already made a CSR request.

I need to say that *certificate_pem* and *private_key* are both encoded in base64, particularly *private_key* is encrypted.

In the code below, i would like to use private_key and certificate_pem.

```
resource "kubernetes_secret" "my-secret" {
  data = {
    "tls.crt" = data.my_data.my-configuration-secret.data["certificate_pem"]
    "tls.key" = data.my_data.my-configuration-secret.data["private_key"]
  }
  metadata {
    name = "my-secret"
    namespace = "my-namespace"
  }
}
```

Now, in the Ingress ressource, i use this secret name

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress" "my-sni" {
  metadata {
    name      = "my-sni"
    namespace = "my_namespace"
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class"                    = "my_namespace"
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http"               = "true"
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect"       = "false"
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect" = "false"
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough"    = "false"
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends"    = "false"
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size"    = "0"
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout" = "3600000"
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target"     = "/$1"
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout" = "400000"
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol"   = "HTTP"

    }
  }
  spec {
    tls {
      hosts = ["my_host"]
      secret_name = "my-secret"
    }
    rule {
      host   = "my_host"
      http {
        path {
          path = "/?(.*)"
          backend {
            service_name = "my-service"
            service_port = 8080
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Everything is fine with *terraform apply*, but i can't go on the host to check if i can access to the microservice.
Someone told me i've to uncypher the private_key.
I don't know how to do that

Comment: Just use `base64encode` built-in function for that: https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/base64encode.

Comment: Does your private key contain `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----`? 
If yes, you could decrypt it with `openssl` like `openssl rsa -in <encrypted_private.key>  -out <decrypted_private.key>`. Be mindful that you may be prompted to enter passphrase to decrypt the key. You can also pass `--passin <Input file pass phrase source>` to write the passphrase to a file & decrypt without the need of the prompt.